# inline img tag background hiding everything else

Tags: html, css, background

I have followed an online tut to get a full-size background using an inline image tag. It works well apart from the fact that every other element is hidden behind it.
I'm sure this is basic, but I can't get my head round it.

```
<style>
body {

}

#bg {
min-height: 800px;
min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>

<nav>
</nav>

<div>
<p>A line</p>
<p>A line</p>
<p>A line</p>
</div>

<img id="bg" src="images/flowers.jpg" alt="flowers" />



</body>
</html>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the `z-index` css property.

Try

```
#bg {
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

Comment: Damn! I was thinking z-index but didn't realise you could use negative numbers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set `z-index to -1`,

```
#bg {
min-height: 800px;
min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by an "inline" background but Im sure you know what you're doing when you put the background as a separate div instead of putting it in the "body" section of your CSS*. Try adding this to your #bg section:

```
z-index: -100;
```

About the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

*It just seems to me that this could work for you:

```
body {
background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat fixed center; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i needed it a minimum size and also to stretch if needed - oh and to work on IE8

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use **z-index** for this.

Give your #bg div a z-index of -1 to correct this issue :)

```
#bg {
min-height: 800px;
min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/KN8na/

Further reading:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Answer (score 0):

```
body {

}

#bg {
z-index: -1000;
background: #ff0;
min-height: 800px;
min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

See solution demo [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjZHk/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You could just move your image up... Then you don't need any extra css.

```
<img id="bg" src="images/flowers.jpg" alt="flowers" />

<div>
<p>A line</p>
<p>A line</p>
<p>A line</p>
</div>
```

But any other solution, like setting `z-index` of the image to a negative value, or setting the image as a background of the body element will also work.